# Inclusion of exogenous variables and prediction of TVAR models (tsDyn package in R)

Tags: r, time-series, multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression, threshold

I'm trying to use the function `TVAR` from tsDyn package in R, but I'm having problems in including exogenous variables.

Also, I still haven't found a way to predict after estimating the model.

What can I do?

Comment: I have looked at the help file for the `TVAR` function and the two vignettes available for the "tsDyn" package, but could not find an answer. While there is an argument `commonInter` in the function `TVAR` that is supposed to specify "whether the deterministic regressors are regime specific (commonInter=FALSE) or not", I do not see how those deterministic regressors can be supplied. I also tried and failed to find whether there is a prediction method for class `TVAR` (that is the class of the object produced by the function `TVAR`).

Answer (score 1):

In the help file appear the following.

```
include = c("const", "trend", "none", "both")
```

You can specify this types of deterministic regressors. I also have a similar problem. I try to specify seasonal dummies or fourier terms to control the seasonality in the model, but i cannot